# AngularJS の directive における replace はどうして DEPRECATED なのですか？

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS の directive における replace はどうして DEPRECATED なのですか？
また replace の代替手段には、どのような方法があるのでしょうか？

参考: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: この[英語版の記事](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194972/why-is-replace-deprecated-in-angularjs)が参考になると思います。

Comment: 理由については上の記事にある通り、セマンティックが複雑でメンテナンスが大変だからみたいですが、具体的にどう大変なのか、また代替案については提示されてないようですね。[該当コミット](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb)を見ても、困るという意見が多い一方で、対応策は現時点であまり書かれていません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。代替手段については英語版を参考にします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**deprecatedにされたコミット**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb)にはこのコメントが添えてありました。

> The `replace` flag for defining directives that
>   replace the element that they are on will be removed in the next
>   major angular version.
>   This feature has difficult semantics (e.g. how attributes are merged)
>   and leads to more problems compared to what it solves.
>   Also, with WebComponents it is normal to have custom elements in the DOM.

要約しますと、`replace`の仕様は定義しづらく（例えば、属性がどうやってマージされるかなど）、`replace`が解決してくれる問題に対して`replace`のせいで生じる問題が多いためでした。そしてWebComponentsにおいてはカスタムな要素を使っても問題ない、ということでした。

以下のSO英語版の答えによると、`replace`がなくなっても、同じ仕様の次善策があるそうです。

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27469582/1945651